# SELECT only latest record of an ID from given rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table shown below...How do I select only the latest data of the id based on changeno?

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| id |  data   | changeno |    |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |   Yes   |     1    |    |
|  2 |   Yes   |     2    |    |
|  2 |  Maybe  |     3    |    |
|  3 |   Yes   |     4    |    |
|  3 |   Yes   |     5    |    |
|  3 |   No    |     6    |    |
|  4 |   No    |     7    |    |
|  5 |  Maybe  |     8    |    |
|  5 |   Yes   |     9    |    |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

I would want this result...

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| id |  data   | changeno |    |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |   Yes   |     1    |    |
|  2 |  Maybe  |     3    |    |
|  3 |   No    |     6    |    |
|  4 |   No    |     7    |    |
|  5 |   Yes   |     9    |    |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

I currently have this SQL statement...

SELECT id, data, MAX(changeno) as changeno FROM Table1 GROUP BY id;

and clearly it doesn't return what I want. This should return an error because of the aggrerate function. If I added fields under the GROUP BY clause it works but it doesn't return what I want. The SQL statement is by far the closest I could think of. I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me on this. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typically referred to as the ["greatest-n-per-group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server?sort=votes&pageSize=50) problem. One way to solve this in SQL Server 2005 and higher is to use a CTE with a calculated `ROW_NUMBER()` based on the grouping of the `id` column, and sorting those by largest `changeno` first:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT id, data, changeno,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY changeno DESC)
  FROM dbo.Table1
)
SELECT id, data, changeno
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Hi, this actually works. Thanks a million :) But do you mind if you could explain a bit about how that ROW_NUMBER works with that PARTITION clause?

Comment: PARTITION BY is like a GROUP BY. For every unique value of id, it looks at all of those rows, and applies a row number ordered by changeno, from largest to smallest. So it looks at id 3, for example, and sees that it has changeno values of 4, 5, and 6. So it orders those in descending order, and applies 1 to 6, then 2 to 5, then 3 to 4. It does this for each id. The outer query pulls only the ones where the row number that was applied was 1. More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Comment: This is weird, but I actually understood everything based on what you said. I'm not as dumb as I thought I am afterall :) @Aaron Bertrand. Thanks a billion this time :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `row_number()` for this:

```
select id, data, changeno
from (SELECT t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by changeno desc) as seqnum
      FROM Table1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This works exactly like the one above, and shorter :) Thanks.

Comment: Oops, sorry I thought I could mark 2 posts as answered, I'll choose yours. @AaronBertrand

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . You're the one who taught me how to read timestamps here.  My answer was 7 seconds earlier.

Comment: Wait... I appreciate both of your answers... I upvoted both answers, but I just can't mark both as answered. I'm so sorry... Ugggh, I feel bad, both of you helped.

Comment: I've also never suggested that timestamp is the only criteria for selecting an answer. I believe I provided a lot more surrounding information in the initial answer *and* was very helpful when the user had follow-up questions too. Surely you don't think 7 seconds trumps that, do you?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . He didn't ask me anything.

Comment: @GordonLinoff uuuuhhhh, ok. I can't control who he asked what, which answer he looked at first, etc.

Comment: Guys, you were both great, and I thank you for that. There was no better answer, both answers were just as great :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a well formed or performance optimized query but for small tasks it works fine.

SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE changeno IN (SELECT MAX(changeno) 
                   FROM TEST 
                   GROUP BY id)

Comment: In addition to the issues you outline, this will only work if we know that `changeno` is unique. Based on the sample data, this is a reasonable assumption, but since we don't know (and since future readers might not know)...

Comment: I believe, if  changeno is not be unique for a given id both the ids should be fetched. @AaronBertrand your solution is great. Got to learn about Partition by Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

*for other alternatives :*

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
 id INT, data VARCHAR(5), changeno INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 1,'Yes',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Yes',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Maybe',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Yes',4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Yes',5
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'No',6
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'No',7
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Maybe',8
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Yes',9

SELECT Y.id, Y.data, Y.changeno
FROM @Table1 Y
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, changeno = MAX(changeno) 
    FROM @Table1 
    GROUP BY id
) X ON X.id = Y.id 
WHERE X.changeno = Y.changeno
ORDER BY Y.id
```